Does "Digital Physics" subscribe to "Simulation Hypothesis" as a non-materialistic philosophical view?
I am trying to understand where modern philosophy draws the line between materialistic and non-materialistic.

Digital physics is a non-materialistic view, which says there is no physicality but only abstract information as the fundamental
building blocks of emergent informational structures of reality, such
as atoms. The digital physics view is non-dualistic in that it does
not juxtapose the terms “abstract” and “physical”, since everything
real is information and therefore abstract. However, just as the
materialist view does not explain where the physical stuff comes from,
the digital physics view does not offer an explanation for where the
information comes from. It just is.
https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC7516678/


So there is a material fact to physics.?

If you consider energy - as a material.

From the first 3 paragraphs of the linked "The Self-Simulation Hypothesis Interpretation"


Introduction and Background

The simulation hypothesis [1] is a materialistic view, which argues
that our universe is most likely a simulation in a physical universe. . . .

In the above view the material is outside conception. We live in the Matrix and we never see the machines outside.

We discuss a non-materialist view called the self-simulation
hypothesis, wherein everything is information, which we define as
thought. . . .

In this view we are self-actualised beings. We have tables and chairs, and if we look closely we see wood-fibres and atoms.  If this is deemed non-material it must be because we only see the surface phenomena. The true material—prime matter—is beyond the penetrative gaze of scientific investigation.  It seems a stretch to deny tables and chairs their materiality.

Materialism is an axiom that says matter and other physical things,
such as light and spacetime, are the fundamental substances of
reality. . . .

Here that which we call 'spacetime' is deemed to be the actual reality of that which it models. We can statistically measure a quantum and declare that that is the most basic measurement of reality (so far). And because that is the most basic discovery it constitutes fundamental reality, because only that which is determined exists as entities. Deeper fundamental discoveries are as yet undiscovered and so they are only possibilities.  Now materialism is looking a lot like the informational wood-fibers and atoms of the self-simulation.
